# Qt - QWidget: Cannot create a QWidget when no GUI is being used

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I'm trying to run a simple `Qt` program, and when doing so, I get a console window mentioning: `QWidget: Cannot create a QWidget when no GUI is being used`, and the second line `This application has requested the Runtime to terminate.....`, and the `.exe` file thus stops working.

My `.pro` file looks as follows:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2011-04-02T07:38:50
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core

QT       += gui

TARGET = Hello
CONFIG += console
CONFIG += qt
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Any ideas on that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

The problem is not with this `.pro`; it is most likely in `main.cpp`.  Qt requires you to create a QApplication before creating any QWidget subclasses (as well as certain other classes, such as QPixmap).  Your `main` function should begin with the line:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
```

and will probably end with a line like:

```
return app.exec();
```

In between these calls, you should create and show your main window.

Answer (score 12):

I found that you can do it with a Qt Console project, but ofcourse it will not have the functionality of a console program when you are done with my edits.

First of all you need to exchange `#include <QtCoreApplication>` with `#include <QApplication>` in your `main.cpp` (where you start your application)

In the `main(int,char**){`

exchange `QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);` with `QApplication a(argc, argv);`

and in between QApplication and return a.exec you have your widget and other gui related stuff

and in the end you use `return a.exec();}`

Answer (score 3):

I think I found where the issue is.

Since I'm using `Qt Creator`, and when creating a new project, I was choosing `Qt Console Application` instead of `Qt Gui Application`.

Comment: Yes, Qt Console Application will create QtCoreApplication which is non-gui and start a console for you. You should use QtApplication instead.

Comment: Another note: GUI requires `QApplication` and `QT+=gui`, and a console requires use of `QCoreApplication` and `CONFIG+=console`. You cannot get a console to display with `QT+=gui` no matter how you link. (You can have two executables, or have one call the other, or implement your own console-like thing from your GUI app.)

Comment: My problem was the same. By changing "QtCoreApplication" to "QtApplication", it worked.

Answer (score 2):

"QWidget: Cannot create a QWidget when no GUI is being used" happens when you application isn't QApplication instance.
From [Qt docs](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/5.0/qapplication.html):

> QApplication specializes QGuiApplication with some functionality
>   needed for QWidget-based applications. It handles widget specific
>   initialization, finalization, and provides session management.
>
> For any GUI application using Qt, there is precisely one QApplication
>   object, no matter whether the application has 0, 1, 2 or more windows
>   at any given time. For non-QWidget based Qt applications, use
>   QGuiApplication instead, as it does not depend on the QtWidgets
>   library.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, 
the **QApplication** class manages the GUI application's control flow and main settings whilst
the **QCoreApplication** class provides an event loop for console Qt applications

I had the same problem, the default QT Console App uses the QCoreApplication instead of the QApplication to run the application.

Here is what i did to make it work

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget widget;

    widget.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

And i did not change anything in my project file

```
QT       += core

QT       += gui

TARGET = Layouts
CONFIG   += gui
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp
```